# Component Error: Uncaught Action failed

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx

I have created a Lightning Aura component to redirect a quick action that creates a record to the newly created record.  This message shows up after the record is created and the user goes into edit and save.[image]

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <aura:dependency resource="markup://force:navigateToSObject" type="EVENT"/>
    <aura:handler event="force:showToast" action="{!c.redirectToNewRecord}"/>
</aura:component>
```

```js
({
    redirectToNewRecord: function(component, event, helper) {
        var messageData = event.getParam('messageTemplateData');
        if (!$A.util.isEmpty(messageData)) {
            var executionComponent = messageData[1].executionComponent;
            if (!$A.util.isEmpty(executionComponent)) {
                var recordId = executionComponent.attributes.recordId;
                var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
                navEvt.setParams({
                    "recordId": recordId,
                    "slideDevName": "related"
                });
                navEvt.fire();
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is because `messageData` doesn't have a value at its *second* index (`messageData[1]`). Have you tried using the first index (`messageData[0]`)? If you are always expecting two items in the `messageData` array, maybe you are better off checking that its length is 2 instead of checking if it is not just empty.

```js
// check first index
var executionComponent = messageData[0].executionComponent;

// OR ensure the length is at least 2
if (!$A.util.isEmpty(messageData) && messageData.length > 1) {
    var executionComponent = messageData[1].executionComponent;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: To add to this answer bascially the error is telling you that `messageData[1]` is undefined and you are trying to reference it.  You will either want to validate it on the client or better yet validate it on the server before you even send it back.